# Non-blocking timer with timer_us of the NewPing library

Tags: timer, arduino, nonblocking

I would like to use the `timer_us` function of the NewPing library in order to run a function every second without blocking. My minimal example looks like this:

```
// setup timer
#include <NewPing.h>
timer_us(1000, sensoring);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200)
}

void loop() {}

void sensoring() {
  Serial.print("ok, it's working")
}
```

But it is not compiling because of:

> expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

My hardware is:

Arduino: 1.8.3 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes:

1. The syntax is `NewPing::timer_ms(`.
2. Put that line inside `setup()`.

Comment: Thank you ver much! By the way: There has been a lot of mistakes ;)

Find the working minimal example here:

`// setup timer
#include <NewPing.h>

void setup() {
  NewPing::timer_ms(1000, sensoring);
  Serial.begin(19200);
}

void loop() {}

void sensoring() {
  Serial.print("ok, it's working");
}`